# Freeing a pointer from another function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function, string, destructor

Given the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class String
{
      char *pstr;
      unsigned size;
      public:
             String(){ pstr=0;size=0;}
             String(const char *);
             void show(){ cout << pstr << endl ; }
             ~String () { cout << "In Dtor" << endl; delete [] pstr; }

};

String::String(const char * cptr)
{
    size = strlen (cptr) + 1;
    cout << "String is - " << cptr << " - of size " << size - 1 << endl ;
    pstr = new char [ size ] ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        pstr[ i ] = cptr [ i ];

}



int main()
{
    String s("Hello World");
    s.show();
    s.~String();
}
```

Output:

```
    String is - Hello World - of size 11
    Hello World
    In Dtor
----Debug Assertion Failure----
    In Dtor
```

Why does the Destructor get called again? When i have invoked the destructor?

And what is an Assertion Failure?

Also is this code Valid?

```
char * ptr=0;    

 void fun()
 {
      const char * p = "Hello World";
      int size = strlen(p )+ 1;
      cout << size << endl;
      ptr = (char *)malloc(size);
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
      ptr[ i ] = p [ i ];
      cout << p << endl << ptr << endl ;
 }

int main()
{
    fun();   
    free (ptr); --> Note
}
```

Can the pointer be freed from another function? This is the main thing i am trying to understand here.

Comment: Don't require an explicit call to the destructor, you aren't using the free store.

Comment: @DumbCoder: Even when using the heap, you don't call the destructor explicitly. You only call `delete`.

Comment: @Acme: On your edit: Yes, you can, but that doesn't really belong to the same question. Also, I'm sure it has been answered before: search before asking!

Comment: @Xeo::If everything could be searched, there was no need of StackOverflow. Do you think SO is the only place you get answers from?

Comment: @Xeo - I assumed that was implied. But you do need to call destructors explicitly if using placement new/memory pools.

Comment: @Acme: Searching on SO itself certainly is an option... But that aside. It doesn't really belong to this question. Ask it as a new question if it wasn't already asked (or you can't find a similar question), so it can be searched for. ;)

Comment: @Xeo::Actually my main problem was regarding the usage of Delete vs Destructor, since we are allocating memory in a different function and destroying in another - this has been a doubt for long. If i am right delete frees the memory being held by the pointer of the object but the object is alive until Destructor is called? Right? Had i made an object using new would then i would have to call the destructor manually? I feel yes, isn't it?

Comment: @Acme: No. when using `new` (which calls the constructor), use `delete` (which calls the destructor). Until you use placement new (new (space) T), you never need to worry about the destructor.

Comment: So, in my case above should i have used delete [] at all in the destructor `~String()` since it goes out of scope anyways once main terminates? What if this object was created in a function which is called from main, in that case the destructor needs a `delete` right?

Comment: @Acme: Yes, you do need the `delete[]` in the destructor, to match the `new[]` in the constructor. The memory leak may not cause a problem in this particular example, but would make the `String` class unusable in a real program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not invoke the destructor manually - it's invoked when `s` goes out of scope at the final '}'

An assertion failure means that something called `assert(somecondition)` and somecondition was false. It's a technique used to validate your assumptions - if your code depends on some specific condition being true, and that condition really should be true unless you have a bug, then you insert an assert.

You can then choose to compile with assertions enabled - this means that you'll get such an error if your assumption was wrong. For a release build, you often disable assertions - no code is generated for the assert statement, and there's no extra runtime cost.

There are cases when it's correct to manually invoke the destructor - You won't need this until you learn about and use "placement new".

Comment: +1 - to clarify: the destructor is getting called once manually, then it's getting called again when `s` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Erik has already said:

Your code would still remain prone to double deletion after you remove manual destructor call: you have to either disable copy constructor/assignment operator, or implement them correctly (you'll need reference counting if you insist on owning heap-allocated memory).

Comment: This should be a comment, no? :)